Fleet couldn't auto-reload changes from build files Error
in Linux (Debian 12.5) i installed Jetbrains Fleet, and downloaded a project compose android from kmp.jetbrains.com,
when i open the project from fleet and enable smart mode, it takes some times indexing the project, at the end i get error message that is:
Gradle: Couldn’t import project
Fleet couldn't auto-reload changes from build files

i tried to open a jetpack compose multiplatform project in fleet. i though it will work without problem, like in windows it works properly until i got that error in every gradle project i try to open

Have you clicked the Details? It should show full output from Gradle including the error.

for my case in this problem, it was just the missing of jdk 17 was not installed, i has only the jdk 22.
after i installed it and set it to JAVA_HOME everything's going well.

sudo apt install default-jdk


I had a similar issue and resolved it by downgrading AGP. I don't think you can use the latest AGP version as it's mostly only supported on Android Studio until IntelliJ/Fleet will support it in a later version. Ensure you use an older AGP version when not working with Android Studio.
